# SIP Python wrapper for C++

Tags: python, python-sip

I am new to SIP. I am trying to create a simple python wrapper for a C++ file. Please help me if you have a sample python wrapper for C++. I have got a sample code. But I am getting the error" sip: string.sip:72: This Python slot requires %MethodCode" when I run the command:
        mkdir sipcode
    cp sipcode-Makefile sipcode/Makefile
    $(SIP) -s ".cc" -c sipcode string.sip

The code for string.sip is mentioned below:

%Module String

namespace std 
{

class string
{

%TypeHeaderCode

## include string.h

%End

public:
    string();

```
string(const char*);
string(const std::string&);

bool empty();
int length();
int size();
void resize(int, char);
void resize(int);
int capacity();
void reserve(int =0);

std::string& append(const std::string&);
std::string& append(const std::string&, int, int);
std::string& append(const char*);
std::string& append(const char*, int);
std::string& append(int, char);

std::string& insert(int, const std::string&);
std::string& insert(int, const std::string&, int, int);
std::string& insert(int, const char*);
std::string& insert(int, const char*, int);
std::string& insert(int, int, char);

int find(const std::string&, int = 0);
int find(const char*, int, int);
int find(const char*, int = 0);
int find(char, int = 0);

int rfind(const std::string&, int = -1);
int rfind(const char*, int, int);
int rfind(const char*, int = -1);
int rfind(char, int = -1);

int find_first_of(const std::string&, int = 0);
int find_first_of(const char*, int, int);
int find_first_of(const char*, int = 0);
int find_first_of(char, int = 0);

int find_first_not_of(const std::string&, int = 0);
int find_first_not_of(const char*, int, int);
int find_first_not_of(const char*, int = 0);
int find_first_not_of(char, int = 0);

int find_last_of(const std::string&, int = 0);
int find_last_of(const char*, int, int);
int find_last_of(const char*, int = 0);
int find_last_of(char, int = 0);

int find_last_not_of(const std::string&, int = 0);
int find_last_not_of(const char*, int, int);
int find_last_not_of(const char*, int = 0);
int find_last_not_of(char, int = 0);

std::string substr(int = 0, int = -1);
```

void **str**();
%MemberCode
    const char* s;
    std::string* ptr;

```
    if (sipParseArgs(&sipArgsParsed,sipArgs,"J1",sipClass_std_string, &ptr))
    {
        s = ptr->c_str();
        /* Python API reference, P40 */
        return PyString_FromString(s);
    }
```

%End

void **getitem**();
%MemberCode
        std::string* ptr;
        int i;

```
    if (sipParseArgs(&sipArgsParsed,sipArgs,"J1i",sipClass_std_string, &ptr, &i))
    {

        if (i >= ptr->length())
        {
                /* Python API Reference, Chapter 4 */
                PyErr_SetString ( PyExc_IndexError  ,"string index out of range" );
                return NULL;
        }
        else

                return Py_BuildValue("c", ptr->at(i));
    }
```

%End

}; 
};